# No overload matches this call on ref={gridRef} from AgGridReact

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to use the useRef hook on ag-grid component AgGridReact with typescript, but I get this overload problem. I am using the community version of ag-grid.

Full error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: AgGridReactProps<any> | AgReactUiProps<any> | Readonly<AgGridReactProps<any> | AgReactUiProps<any>>): AgGridReact<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<AgGridReact<any> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<AgGridReact<any>> | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<AgGridReact<any> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<AgGridReact<any>>'.
        Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
          Type 'AgGridReact<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'AgGridReact<any> | null'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'AgGridReact<any> | null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: AgGridReactProps<any> | AgReactUiProps<any>, context: any): AgGridReact<any>', gave the following error.
```

My code:

```
 const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>();

 const onGridReady = () => {
    gridRef.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CommonTitle> Create a new project </CommonTitle>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "80vh" }}>
        <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          animateRows={true}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

imports:

```
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import { ColDef } from "ag-grid-community";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
```

version:

```
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^28.2.1",
```

................................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the initial value to null in the `useRef` function call

```
const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null)
```

This ensures that `gridRef = AgGridReact | null` which is what the ref prop is expecting rather than `AgGridReact | undefined`.